# I'm at a loss on how to loop this?

Tags: jquery, animation, carousel

Well, before this project I knew NOTHING about jQuery. I still know basically nothing, but still.

Anyways, the end goal is to create a slider gallery. This gallery should run infinitely, with no skipping or tears. Thanks to the numerous questions I've already asked you guys, (Thanks for the help by the way.) I've got it to this point...

http://jsfiddle.net/75MDR/

But I have NO idea how to get that animation to repeat itself. I've done a little bit of research, and thought perhaps I could use the .before property to take the last image and slap it behind the other one. Perhaps something like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#image").animate({"margin-left":"+=400px"}, 3000, "linear");
function gallery () {
    $("#image").animate({"margin-left":"+=400px"}, 3000, "linear");
            $("image3").before( $("image") );
}
setInterval(gallery, 3000);
});
```

But, I have two problems with that. The firs being that that code does absolutely nothing The second is that I'm not sure how I would time it. Perhaps is there a way to check if it has left the frame?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your approach that you are going to need to address. Namely, you will need to address the use of better selectors; the issue of having your code properly wrapped to call;  and you will need to manage where your image is.

**Use better selectors**

jQuery selection is based pretty much on **css selectors**.

*id selection*

In css if you want to style an element with `id="hello"` then you would use `#id{ color: blue; }`. In jQuery if you want to target an element with `id="hello"` then you would use `$("#hello")`. See the correlation? Keep in mind, **you should only use unique ids**.

*class selection*

If you want to target more than one element, uses classes. In css if you wanted to select all the elements with `class="world"` then you would use `.world{ background-color:yellow; }`. In jQuery if you wanted to target all the elements with `class="world"` then you would use `$('.world')`. Again note the correlation.

*complex selection*

There are more complex selectors that you can choose. For your exact situation, I would suggest using `img[class^=image]` and getting rid of the ids altogether. That selector says "select all image elements which have a class that starts with image". If you wanted to use this selector for css, you would use `img[class^=image]{ position: relative; }`. If you wanted to use this selector for jQuery, you would use `$('img[class^=image]').animate({});`. Sorry to be repetitive, but again.. the correlation :P

**Wrap your code**

*naming conventions*

What is it that you want to do? Can you state it in a few words, if so, make a function with that name.

```
function slideGallery(){}
```

*define your goals*

Then go through your function and define the process you wish to handle. If you really want to accomplish the goals defined in your question, then there are some non trivial aspects you will need to take into consideration.

```
function slideGallery()
{
 //will animation cause an image to leave the screen? (hint: think collision detection)
 //if so, clone image leaving screen and place it at the start (hint: $(element).clone())
 //animate all images
 //remove image which left screen (hint: $(element).remove())
}
```

**Where is your image?**

Keeping track of your image is definitely non trivial.

*viewport*

First you have to be aware not specifically what the size of the document is, but what the size of the viewport is. If you take into consideration scrollbars this can become a little hard. However, since you can push the image off the screen at will that isn't an issue. All you really need is to ask jQuery what the window width is.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
```

*image location*

Next you need to keep track of where your image is as it animates. This can be done with jQuery's offset.

```
//target current image animating
var currentImage = however you decide to access the image
var currentImageOffset = $(currentImage).offset().left;
if( currentImageOffset + animationWidth > windowWidth ) //collision will occur
```

*image placement*

Now you need to do is keep track of where the first image started off so that when you clone all of your images, you can place that one there. This means gathering the first images data before everything begins to animate.

```
var baseImagePosition = $('.image').offset().left;
```

---

Putting all of these things together should give you a scrolling gallery.